# Sonarqube run analysis without removing existing issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Issues for the entire project is reported whenever I run analysis for the entire project. But when I run analysis for only the changed files next day the issues of other files are getting deleted.

Is there any way to preserve the issues of other files when I run with `-Dsonar.inclusions`?

Comment: Why do you only analyse the changed files? Is your concern the analysis performance?

Comment: Yes. My concern is about the performance. Each day only few files will get changed. But for that entire project analysis is required. But actually analysis of those files will only take minimum amount of time when compared to full project analysis.

Answer (score 4):

SonarQube expects you to analyse all files every time. Depending on the analysed languages this is especially important for the "cross file analysis" (issues raised on one file, because of the changes in another file).

Depending on your language and build environment, you could however consider to split your project into smaller independent projects. If you for example split one big java/maven project into smaller ones and let SonarQube have access to all those dependencies, you will have faster build and analysis times.

Comment: I can understand that full analysis is needed for cross file analysis case. But in my sure I will be sure that the added files won't affect any other issues expect the issues of files for which the analysis is triggered. So in this case is there any analysis parameter to explicitly say sonarqube to preserve the issues of other files?

Comment: @manoj-kumar Maybe the branch feature could be used, but I am not a specialist of it. I do not know of any other solution.